# Get original path of selected file from input type file in PHP

Tags: php

I want to get original selected file path (path from where i selected file) using PHP from input type file.

In other relavant questions about this all says about $FILE['tmp_name'] and using JavaScript.but I need this solution using PHP code.

Can any one know about this. (Thanks in advance)

Comment: There is not such a thing in `$_FILE` variable. In some browsers you can get it, for more info read this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Comment: So is it possible to read that file after selecting and without uploading using tmp_name